# Access Violation Writing to location

Tags: c++, char, ifstream, getline, istream

Im new to c++ and I dont know what this error means. It reads from a file and tries to store the values in a char * [].

The file contains:

```
5,Justin,19,123-45-6789,State Farm,9876,Jessica,Broken Hand,
```

This is my code.

```
void Hospital::readRecordsFile(){
std::ifstream fileStream;
fileStream.open(fileName); // Opens the file stream to read fileName
char * temp [8];
int i = 0;
while(!fileStream.eof()){
    fileStream.get(temp[i],256,',');
    i++;
}
i = 0;
for(char * t:temp){
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

}

The error is at the line `fileStream.get(temp[i],256,',');`

Comment: What both answers below want to tell you is that the array `temp` contains 8 uninitialized pointers to char (8 random values, in fact). Since a pointer variable stores the address in memory of another variable, you attempt to write at random memory addresses (which, most of the times, are not writeble). The OS handles this erratic behaviour: it displays the error message and terminates the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define an array of 8 pointers to char, but forget to allocate memory so that the pointers point to a valid chunk of memory:

```
char * temp [8]; // need then to allocate memory for the pointers
```

Because of this, in the line

```
fileStream.get(temp[i],256,',')
```

you end up using memory that's not yours.

Solution:

```
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    temp[i] = new char[256]; // we allocate 256 bytes for each pointer
```

Better though, use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

---

In the code you have right now it looks like you implicitly assume that the file has no more than 8 lines, which I find hard to believe. If your file has more than 8 lines, then you'll end up accessing the array of 8 pointers out of bounds, so you'll get another undefined behaviour (usually a segfault). That's why is much better to use standard STL containers like `std::vector`, to avoid all these headaches.

In case you MUST use pointers and want a variable number of lines, then you have to use a pointer to pointer,

```
char** temp;
```

then allocate memory for an enough pointers-to-char,

```
temp = new char* [1000]; // we believe we won't have more than 1000 lines
```

then, for each pointer-to-char, allocate memory

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    temp[i] = new char[256];
```

At the end of the program, you must then `delete[]` in reverse order

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    delete[] temp[i];

delete[] temp;
```

As you can see, it's getting messy.

Comment: The `std::vector<std::string>` may not be appropriate if the records are fixed length and not text.

Comment: @Thomas is right. However, it would still be substantially _more_ appropriate than the existing "solution".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Lightning that's true, I actually wonder what is the best container to use in this case... perhaps a container of smart pointers.

Comment: Ok so when I declare the char * [], I never initialize it? I just declare, is that correct?

Comment: If this is block reading from a file, I would use a single buffer that is 8 * 256. *And not use dynamic memory.*

Comment: `std::array<unsigned char, 256>` seems appropriate

Comment: @Jimenemex, no, you declare an array of 8 pointers. Now, each pointer have to point to some valid address. In your case, they are not. That's why you need to either allocate memory to point to or point them to an already allocated chunk.

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes indeed, I just saw that OP is always reading 256 bytes, and only 8 lines. But probably this is not the intention, as the files can have variable number of lines. If indeed there are only 8 lines, then a std::array is the way to go.

Comment: @vsoftco I mean an array for each line (if he really intends that 256 should be the line, as opposed to him doing that because he didn't know any better)

Comment: @MattMcNabb got it, also my wild guess is that OP intention is not reading anything in binary format, but plain text from a file. But indeed, if the line has to be fixed (which probably is not the case here), an `std::array` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You never allocated memory for each pointer in `temp`.
You probably want something like:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0u; i < 8; ++i)
{
  temp[i] = new char[256];
}
```

The says that the `temp` variable points to 8 dynamically allocated byte buffers of 256 bytes each.

Comment: Funny how both of us choose `256` as the size :) But why `uint8_t` and not simply `char`? AFAIK `char` is fine, being the smallest addressable thing.

Comment: It _should_ be `char`. Don't forget to support those `CHAR_BIT != 8` architectures! :P

Comment: Changed array type from `uint8_t` to `char`, *per OP's question*.